# Comparing the performance of two teams measuring many variables once

Tags: distributions, paired-data

Which statistical tools are best suited for this problem:

Team A goes and measures 3 magnitudes in 200 locations (let's imagine the volume of a room, the insulation coefficient and the average temperature outside the room).  For each room they calculate the energy this room will consume to keep the desired temperature for a week.

So after the measurement campaign they have measured these 3 magnitudes in 200 different rooms (each room is only measured once).  So the data looks like:

```
 (Room_volume, r_coefficient, T, estimated_energy)
```

Team A is assumed to be very good at getting their results. Now team B measures the same 200 rooms, and calculates all the estimated energies for each room.

How should we measure the performance of team B vs team A (where A is assumed to be accurate)?

Forgetting the physics, as it's just an illustrative example, how do you compare the accuracy of a measurement campaign measuring 3 values from which a 4th one can be calculated deterministically?  Note that none of these values are distributed in any special way among the 200 samples (they don't look gaussian)

I started looking at the distribution of errors, so:

```
 {Estimated_energy_Ai - Estimated_energy_Bi} with i = 1..200
```

And seeing how many results are within a standard deviation.  What other tools are appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

If you are 100% sure your data is non-normal, then you can perform a T-test to say if the two results are significantly different.

if your data sets have equal sample and variance

try using `scipy.stats.ttest_rel`

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html

Comment: Unfortunately the two data sets have different variance. Is there a version that can account for that?

Comment: You if variance are different then you can try a two sample t test. you can try [t test for unequal variance](http://mathnstats.com/index.php/hypothesis-testing/82-tests-for-means/122-two-sample-t-test-unequal-variances.html). Check the examples from [scipy stat ttest independent](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html#scipy.stats.ttest_ind)